# Github Page, link to html in another repo

Tags: github-pages

I have a [github pages sites](https://jason-hanser.github.io/) and I am trying to link to an html file (block-schedule-walkthrough-p1.html) stored in one of my [repositories](https://github.com/jason-hanser/block-schedule). My github page's source is set as master and, based on what I have seen, I should just be able to format the links like this:

https://<user_name>.github.io/<repo_name>/<file_name>

So I used this as my link:

https://jason-hanser.github.io/block-schedule/block-schedule-walkthrough-p1.html

However, if I click on that link (or enter the address in my browser), I get a 404 error and I don't know why.

Can anyone help? I'm somewhat new to github and completely new to github pages.

Edit: On my page there are two links: Attempt_1 and Attempt_2. Attempt_1 is what I am talking about here. For Attempt_2 I used htmlpreview, but I'd like to be able to do it the other way.

Answer (score 2):

**I think your block-schedule repo is not published under Github Pages.**

To publish your repo:

1. Head to the repo's [settings page](https://github.com/jason-hanser/block-schedule/settings).
2. Scroll down to the Github Pages section.
3. Your source must currently be set to "None". Change it to "master branch".

[image: changing from none → master branch]

4. Wait for some time and your site will be live at https://jason-hanser.github.io/block-schedule/

Hope my answer helps. I'm also new to Github pages!

Answer (score 0):

#### Try renaming `lock-schedule-walkthrough-p1.html` to `index.html`

Why?

The root HTML file should always be called index.html, that's how hosts are able to know which file to display.

Comment: Okay, I edit the file and the link so that it directs to: https://jason-hanser.github.io/block-schedule/index.html. But I am still getting a 404 error.

Comment: That's because it's available at: https://jason-hanser.github.io/#block-schedule-project/